# How to filter a UML diagram in IntelliJ to show only specific classes and their transitive dependencies?

Tags: intellij-idea, dependencies, uml

I have a Java/Kotlin/Lombok project with around 800 classes and I want to see the relationship + transitive dependencies for 60 of them. I know that IntelliJ has a UML diagram feature, which I'm using, but it tries to load 100s of classes at once and it's not what I need.

Is there a way for me to filter to only the 60 classes I want plus their transitive dependencies only? (I don't need to see upstream dependencies).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a [scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-scopes.html) which includes only needed files: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/scope-language-syntax-reference.html and select this scope in the [Project tool window](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/project-tool-window.html) and then invoke UML diagram on those files.